# Concatenating a column to a matrix (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

I have a matrix `b` and I need to put some of its columns (for example columns 2,4) to another empty matrix `a`. Based on following code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty([2, 1])
b = np.array([[1, 8, 6, 3], [3, 0, 7, 4]])
```

So I want a to a be like this:

```
[[8,3][0,4]]
```

I tried `np.concatenate`:

```
np.concatenate((a,b[:,1]),axis=0)
```

but got this error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Can anyone please explain to me how should I fix this error? Or is there any other way rather than `np.concatenate` that I can use?

Thank you.

Comment: What you want is a `(2,2)` array, but you initial `a` to a `(2,1)`.  Did you look at `b[:,1]`?  I expect it is `[8,0]`, just 2 of the numbers you want.  Forget about `concatenate` at this time, and focus on indexing `b` correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is just

```
cols = [1, 3]
a = b[:, cols]
```

You don't need to initialise an empty matrix `a` for this purpose, nor do you need to concatenate.

Just a reminder: python uses 0-based indexing. According to your desired example solution, you are probably looking for columns `1, 3`, not `2, 4`.

In case you actually *do* want to concatenate (for example if `a` is not empty, but you would like to append more columns to it, you can do it as you suggested, but along `axis=1`. Be careful though as at the moment you are concatenating columns to an empty matrix with non-initialised entries.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [**copy( )**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html#numpy-copy)  function in numpy module to copy matrices.
Here is the solution :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b = np.array([[1, 8, 6, 3], [3, 0, 7, 4]])
>>> a = b[0::,1::2].copy() 
>>> print a
[[8 3]
[0 4]]
```

*Things become more complex when multidimensional arrays are indexed, particularly with multidimensional index arrays.*
Go through the [**documentation**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) for understanding Indexing in Multi-dimensional arrays and 
[**here**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#combining-index-arrays-with-slices) is the array indexing documentation with slices in **Numpy module**.